# What is the EDGE api that appears in the phonegap docs?

Tags: cordova

I was looking at phonegap api docs. I came across `EDGE` in the version dropdown. I googled the diff between the regular phonegap versions api and `EDGE`. But could not find anything strong. Can someone let me know about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

edge should be the latest version. a kind of work in progress for the next version.

Comment: So, that means it is a beta unstable nightly build thing. I won't use it for production for sure.