# What does "edge" version mean?

Tags: version, microsoft-edge

I've been wondering about this since the latest version of Internet explorer. It has an emulate function as most of you might know, this is where we test for the prehistoric versions of Internet explorer by changing the document mode.

[image]

The default document mode is "Edge". I thought this was IE specific, but aparently it has something to do with versions.

I recently noticed that when selection a jQuery version on jsfiddle.com you can select 1.x and 2.x "edge" versions.

[image]

What does this mean? What exactly is an "Edge" version?

Aparently it's the "latest" version. Some extra info would be nice though, like when to use Edge in stead of the actual version number.

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073272/what-is-the-edge-api-that-appears-in-the-phonegap-docs?rq=1)

Comment: I thought it meant the latest "x." branch release

Comment: @Shanimal Would that mean that IE won't be increasing their list with document mode's from now on? So on release of 12, the list will become 5,6,7,8,9,10,Edge . Skipping 11? Otherwise I won't know what value it will have to name it Edge in stead of the latest version.

Comment: I haven't figured out how to message you... It's just asking if you always want the edge version. In the emulation screenshot 10 would be edge. Then 11 would be edge after they release it. In the second screenshot its telling you that x means the latest minor version.

Comment: @Shanimal See the updated question. Why would they call it Edge in stead of just the actual version number?

Comment: i think it depends, with package managers for instance, if you specify edge it will always look for the latest. sometimes CDN's will give you a way to specify edge, no matter what it is. Its like a variable in that case... Google for instance allows you to grab edge by not specifiying a minor release google.load("search", "1");

Comment: @Shanimal That actually makes a lot of sense =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered in the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073272/what-is-the-edge-api-that-appears-in-the-phonegap-docs?rq=1), "Edge" means the latest version.

The reason Shanimal suggested seems logical to me.

When referring, including or linking the latest version, one could always implement "Edge". This will then automaticaly mean the latest. Especialy for includes this can come in handy.